# Taylor remainder calculation

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

This is a dumb question maybe. I have a PDF with the most important Taylor expansions calculated in 0.
My question is: how do I find the Lagrange remainder of a certain order from the PDF without calculating all the derivatives again?

Answer (score 0):

Once you have calculated the taylor expression, you don't need to compute the derivatives again, just derive one more time.

Notice you will always need the last derivative of the series expansion, so if you don't have it, you will have to derive the given function to the order required plus one.

Most of the times, in basic and academic exercises the given functions follow a pattern when deriving, so try to find out first if you can figure out any pattern.